# Showing surjectivity of piecewise functions

Tags: functions

$f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{0}, f(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}2 x-1, & x>0 \\ -2 x, & x \leq 0\end{array}\right.$

I have problems showing that this function is surjective, mainly formally. I probably would distinguish beetween  $y \in\{2 \tilde{n}-1 \mid \hat{n}>0\}$
and
$y \in\{-2 \tilde{n} \mid \tilde{n} \leq 0\}$, but how do i write it down formally?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean quite by "formally" but, if you want to show surjectivity, all you need to show is that every element of $\mathbb{N}_0$ is in the image of $f$. So given an arbitrary $y \in \mathbb{N}_0$, you need to prove that $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

You may find that it helps to split by cases. If $y \in \mathbb{N}_0$ is even, can you find an $x$ which maps to $y$? What if $y$ is odd?